# How to change style of grid lines to dotted or dashed in Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, css, google-visualization

Before Google has deprecated the Google Image Charts, was possible to change the grid lines style on charts using the parameter **chg**. You can check it here:
[example of chart with dashed grid lines](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chs=550x230&chd=t:100,50,115,80&chxt=x,y&chxl=1:%7CPython%7CJava%7CRuby%7C.NET&chxr=0,0,120&chds=0,120&chco=4D89F9&chbh=35,0,15&chg=8.33,0,5,5)

*Obs: To change the dash style just change chg=8.33,0,**5,5** to chg=8.33,0,**3,3**, for example.*

*Source: http://psychopyko.com/tutorial/how-to-use-google-charts/*

Now in the new Google Charts, I would like to do the same.
I have tried many ways and got a possible solution changing the **CSS**.
Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/R4DGp/

However I would like to know if there is a cleaner solution without changing directly in the **CSS**. May something like [lineDashStyle](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines#dashed-lines), but for grid lines.

**JS**

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Game', 'Pts', 'Agt'],
        [1, 21, 32],
        [2, 18, 23],
        [3, 27, 17],
        [4, 35, 24],
        [5, 23, 10],
        [6, 20, 21],
        [7, 28, 24],
        [8, 17, 21],
        [9, 22, 20],
        [10, 13, 28],
        [11, 27, 13],
        [12, 31, 28],
        [13, 23, 21],
        [14, 28, 27],
        [15, 17, 20],
        [16, 13, 17]
    ]);

    var options = {
        'focusTarget': 'category',
        'lineWidth': 0.75,
        'hAxis': {
            'color': 'none',
            'baselineColor': 'none',
            'textStyle': {
                'color': '#8C8C8C',
                'fontName': 'Calibri',
                'fontSize': 12,
            },
        },
        'vAxis': {
            'color': 'none',
            'baselineColor': 'none',
            'textStyle': {
                'color': '#8C8C8C',
                'fontName': 'Calibri',
                'fontSize': 12,
            },
        },
        'legend': 'none',
        'curveType': 'function',
        'legend': 'none',
        'pointSize': 7,
        'colors': ['#9FAEC2', '#e2431e'],
        'crosshair': {
            trigger: 'none'
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**CSS**

```
svg g g g rect + rect{
    fill: none;
    fill-opacity: 0.5;
    stroke: gray; 
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke-dasharray: 7 6;
    width:0.5;
}
svg g g g circle{
    fill:black;
}
    svg g g g circle:hover{
        stroke:yellow;
        stroke-width:2;
        fill 
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: We don't currently support the ability to do this.

Comment: If you want nice lines than you will have to exchange rectangles with lines. Which is not trivial work.